# net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps make service timeout

Tags: tcp

We have a service that calls a third-party service.
But when calling their authentication interface, it will trigger a connection timeout.
At this time, accessing any of their interfaces will timeout.
However, there is no such phenomenon when accessing other interfaces.

After they changed net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=0, the timeout no longer occurred.

Comment: This is not about programming and thus off-topic here. But a search for [tcp_timestamps connection timeout](https://www.google.com/search?q=tcp_timestamps+connection+timeout) points to [Communications fail between Azure Load Balancer and SLE instance](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019510) which point to [Azure Load Balancer health probes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-custom-probe-overview#limitations) which says *"You should assume health probes fail when TCP timestamps are enabled."*. So this seems to be a problem in specific environments.